# insert UTF-8 characters into sql server 2008 table

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, encoding, utf-8

I'm inserting an email content text as UTF-8 string using php into an SQL server 2008 database table and it is working fine except one specific email.

The INSERT command fails with this error:

> An error occurred translating the query string to UTF-16: No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page.

The text that causes it is an extension text of a phone number:

[image]

this "xF7" that supposed to be +91-98XXXXXXX (i added the XX) must have turned into UTF-16 or something?

before insert into the database I did a UTF-8 check using mb_detect_encoding:

```
$HTMLencode = mb_detect_encoding(HTMLString, mb_detect_order(), true);
```

$PLAINencode = mb_detect_encoding(PLAINString, mb_detect_order(), true);

as you can see I even take under consideration a "multipart email" - part of HTML and a part of PLAIN text.
both checks return **UTF-8** (which means the "xF7" fooled me.. :))

I also did iconv() using UTF-8//IGNORE in order to ignore invalid characters,
nothing helps, how do I solve this in php?

The code above works fine for 99% of the emails except that one special one that raise this error.

Answer (score 1):

`0xF7` encodes `÷` in Windows-1252. Are you just passing data directly to database?

You should use an email library that reads the email headers correctly, which state the character encoding that is being used in the email. The library would then ideally convert from that encoding to UTF-8 before handing it to you.

`mb_detect_encoding` is virtually useless because it just has access to the bytes and doesn't apply any heuristics either. It is especially useless if it gives UTF-8 for a string that has `0xF7`, which cannot appear in UTF-8

Comment: thank you, i'm not passing is straight , i do this before insert: $PLAINText = iconv("UTF-8","UTF-8//IGNORE",$PLAINText); . there are so many posts that suggest it ,but it doesn't work for me and there are others who this didn't clean the invalid characters for them...

Comment: @Rodniko I guess you didn't understand. Those little hacks are complete bs, all you need to do is to read the email headers and use the encoding claimed in the email header to decode the email. Because the hacks are bs, you *are* passing the email straight to insert.